# XSLT : recall of variables in templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am stuck in my XSL sheet. My transformation fails to replace the image file without extension and the incremented position in the `@xml:id` of the different `<zone>`.

I'm trying to get from a collection of Alto files the following output :

```
<facsimile>
      <surface facs="#FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1">
         <graphic url="FRAN_0025_0039_L-1.jpeg" xml:id="FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1"/>
         <zone type="PrintSpace" xml:id="facPS_FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1" ulx="0" uly="0" lrx="2972" lry="4356">
            <zone type="TextBlock" xml:id="facblock_FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1">
               <zone type="TextLine" xml:id="facline_FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1" ulx="2575" uly="284" lrx="2830" lry="348">
                  <zone type="String" xml:id="facs_FRAN_0025_0039_L-1_1" ulx="2575" uly="284" lrx="2830" lry="348"/>
               </zone>
            </zone>
         </zone>
      </surface>
      <surface>
         <!-- ... -->
      </surface>
      <surface>
         <!-- ... -->
      </surface>
   </facsimile>
```

and this is what I get :

```
<facsimile xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <surface facs="#FRAN_0025_0043_L-0_1">
      <graphic url="FRAN_0025_0043_L-0.jpg" xml:id="#FRAN_0025_0043_L-0_1"/>
      <zone type="PrintSpace"
            xml:id="facPS__1"
            ulx="0"
            uly="0"
            lrx="3006"
            lry="4356">
         <zone type="TextBlock" xml:id="facblock__">
            <zone type="TextLine"
                  xml:id="facline__"
                  ulx="2621"
                  uly="275"
                  lrx="2888"
                  lry="342">
               <zone type="String"
                     xml:id="facs__"
                     ulx="2621"
                     uly="275"
                     lrx="2888"
                     lry="342"/>
            </zone>
            <zone type="TextLine"
                  xml:id="facline__"
                  ulx="544"
                  uly="288"
                  lrx="695"
                  lry="355">
               <zone type="String"
                     xml:id="facs__"
                     ulx="544"
                     uly="288"
                     lrx="695"
                     lry="355"/>
            </zone>
            <!-- ... -->
```

my XSL stylesheet :

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ns="http://www.namescape.nl/"
    xmlns:alto="http://schema.ccs-gmbh.com/ALTO"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei ns alto xsl xs"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v4#"
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="DOCUMENT" select="collection('catalog_alto.xml')"/>
    <xsl:param name='scale'>1</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <facsimile>
                <xsl:for-each select="$DOCUMENT">
                    <xsl:variable name="image_filename" select="descendant::Description/sourceImageInformation/fileName/text()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="image_filename_without_extension" select="substring-before($image_filename, '.jpg')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                <surface>
                    <xsl:attribute name="facs">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('#',$image_filename_without_extension, '_',$i)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <graphic>
                        <xsl:attribute name="url">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$image_filename"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('#',$image_filename_without_extension, '_',$i)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </graphic>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="./descendant::*[local-name()='Layout']" mode="facsimile">
                        <xsl:with-param name="image_filename_without_extension" select="$image_filename_without_extension" tunnel="yes"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$i"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </surface>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </facsimile>
            <text>
                <body>
                    <div>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="./descendant::*[local-name()='Layout']"/>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </text> 
    </xsl:template> 
    
    <xsl:template match="descendant::*[local-name()='Layout']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
 
    <xsl:function name="ns:scaleCoordinates">
        <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value * $scale"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='PrintSpace' or local-name()='TextLine' or local-name()='TextBlock' or local-name()='String']" mode="facsimile">
        <xsl:param name="image_filename_without_extension"/>
        <xsl:param name="position"/>
        <zone>  
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="local-name()='PrintSpace'">
                <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('facPS_', $image_filename_without_extension, '_', $position)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="local-name()='TextLine'">
                <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('facline_', $image_filename_without_extension, '_', $position)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="local-name()='TextBlock'">
                <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('facblock_', $image_filename_without_extension, '_', $position)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="local-name()='String'">
                <xsl:attribute name="xml:id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('facs_', $image_filename_without_extension, '_', $position)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@HPOS and @WIDTH">
                <xsl:attribute name="ulx" select="ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@HPOS))"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="uly" select="ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@VPOS))"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="lrx"
                    select="ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@HPOS)) + ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@WIDTH))"/>
                <xsl:attribute name="lry"
                    select="ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@VPOS)) + ns:scaleCoordinates(xs:integer(@HEIGHT))"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
        </zone>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think this is a problem with the different if conditions and variable callbacks with param, but I don't see why I manage to get the position for the `@xml:id` of my first zone (*facPS__1*) but not for the others.

An idea, a tip? thank you for your time and good to you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of code but it seems to want to use `tunnel="yes"` on that `position` parameter you pass down with apply-templates if you expect it to show up further down the hierarchy. So both on the `xsl:with-param` inside of `apply-templates` as well as in the "receiving" template where you declare `xsl:param` make sure you use `tunnel="yes"`.

Comment: Ok this works fine, I didn't know we could use the `tunnel = 'yes'` parameter on `xsl:param` in the "receiver" template. Thank you